# Java operands different consistency

Tags: java, decimalformat

Do you know if there is any rule statement to follow regarding the feasible arithmetic operations among different representations? 
For instance:7

```
int a = 0342342;
int b = 0x1abcdef; 
int c = a +b;
System.out.println("It prints out : "+c);
```

It prints out : 28152529
.

The results (c) is a decimal representation of the addition of the 2 operands a and b.

What if I wanted the result in a particular representation format different from the decimal format?

Comment: Use `System.out.printf`, if you want more flexibility, you can use `Integer.toString(int base)`

Comment: `a` is octal start with `0`, `b` is hex start with `0x`. `C` you printed out in decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print in hex do like this

```
System.out.printf("It prints out %x\n", c);
```

Comment: [java Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 2):

The numbers `0342342` and `0x1abcdef` are literal representations of integers that Java supports for the convenience of developers. Within Java, there really is only one representation of that integer and it is stored in the `int` type with no reference to a number base (like octal or hexadecimal).

By default, when you print an `int`, it is displayed in the decimal format.

If you want some other format, you should use [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.printf("Decimal: %d",c);
System.out.printf("Octal: %o",c);
System.out.printf("Hexadecimal: %x",c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.format` in order to represent in different format.

You can find more detailed answer in here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html